# Query returning multiple values for the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am running a simple query and asking to return the same column from the same table twice. For some reason, the column returns with two different results. Can someone please explain why and show me how to ask the query to return consistent results twice?

Here is the code I am running:

```
SELECT WIN1.SERVERNAME,
       WIN1.APPLICATION AS 'App 1',
       WIN1.STATUS      AS 'Status 1',
       WIN1.IPADDRESS   AS 'WIN1 IP',
       WIN2.APPLICATION AS 'App 2',
       WIN2.STATUS      AS 'Status 2',
       WIN2.IPADDRESS   AS 'WIN2 IP'
FROM   SERVER.WINDOWS WIN1,
       SERVER.WINDOWS WIN2
WHERE  WIN1.IPADDRESS IS NOT NULL
       AND WIN2.IPADDRESS IS NOT NULL
       AND WIN1.SERVERNAME LIKE '%SERVER NAME%'
       AND WIN1.STATUS LIKE '%line%'
       AND WIN2.STATUS LIKE '%line%'
       AND WIN2.APPLICATION LIKE '%APPLICATION NAME%'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are missing a join criteria between the two instances of the table so are getting a cross join. Show some example data and explain what you are trying to do

Comment: You might do better to explain what you're trying to attempt.  Joins either 1) multiply rows based on joining conditions or 2) remove rows entirely from the dataset if there is no match on join.  Using `LIKE` is going to make it worse as a Join condition because it's not a one-to-one join with the same exact word.  As others have pointed out- your code is suspect.  And it's difficult to understand what you're attempting from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the same table twice to your query is similar to doing a full outer join, you are joining the table against itself, the where clauses make things harder to figure it out, just call the query without any filter to understand the effect of the query calling the same table twice.

From this point you should be able to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
SELECT WIN1.SERVERNAME,
   WIN1.APPLICATION AS 'App 1',
   WIN1.STATUS      AS 'Status 1',
   WIN1.IPADDRESS   AS 'WIN1 IP',
   WIN2.APPLICATION AS 'App 2',
   WIN2.STATUS      AS 'Status 2',
   WIN2.IPADDRESS   AS 'WIN2 IP'
FROM   SERVER.WINDOWS WIN1,
   SERVER.WINDOWS WIN2
```

OR

```
Select * FROM   
   SERVER.WINDOWS WIN1,
   SERVER.WINDOWS WIN2
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That makes sense.  I was running the way I had it set up because I read you could call the same column twice by simply listing it twice with two different names. Clearly that was bad advice, and you have explained why.